# C++:Generics >> How to define several template deklarations for a generic function, which serves as an static instance creator

Tags: c++, generics

I'm working on some stuff with instances and wondering, is it possible to create a generic instance creation function for a class/struct and its following derivates.

I have 2 problems and a question for possibility:

1. to make it work, that the generic function can at least deliver an instance of the class/struct itself, the function is living/existing in. --> got undefined reference error
2. to make  it work , that the generic function can deliver several types of instances --> got undefined reference type error
3. is it possible to make it work, that the generic function deliver types of future derived types, by implementing further template declarations in these derivates. So the base class with the generic function don't need to know about them( and by my understanding of the situation, never can , because how knows what future children/derivates will follow )

I prepared a example for  better understanding:

```
//base.hpp

struct base {

    base(int param1, int param2) : a(param1), b(param2)
    {}

    private:
        int a,b;

    public:
    
        template <typename T> static T createInstanceGeneric(int param1, int param2){
            return T(param1, param2); 
        }

        //Thats of course working//
        static base createInstance(int param1, int param2) { 
            return base(param1, param2);
        }
        void update(int param2){
            _update(0, param2);
        }

        void process() { int tmp = a; a = b; b = tmp }

    protected:
       void _update(int param1, int param2){
            a = param1;
            b = param2;
       }    
}
//END base.hpp

//childOne.hpp
#include "base.hpp"
struct childOne : public base {

    childOne(int param1, int param2) : base(param1, param2 ){}

    //Thats of course working//
    static base createInstanceOfBase(int param1, int param2) { 
            return  base::createInstance(param1, param2);
        }

    static childOne createInstanceOfSelfViaGeneric(int param1, int param2) { 
            return base::createInstanceGeneric<childOne>(param1, param2);
        }

    static base createInstanceOfBaseViaGeneric(int param1, int param2) { 
            return  base::createInstanceGeneric<base>(param1, param2);
        }
    void update(int param1){
        base::_update(param1, 0);
    }                   

}
//END childOne.hpp

//app.cpp
#include "childOne.hpp"


void calledLaterForSomeStuff( const base& data  ){
    data.process();
}

void main()
{
    base test1 = base::createInstance(0,1); //Working
    test1.update(2);
    calledLaterForSomeStuff(test1);

    base test2 = childOne::createInstanceOfBase(0,1); //Working
    test2.update(2);
    calledLaterForSomeStuff(test2); 

    //undefined reference to `base base::createInstanceGeneric<base>(int param1, int param2)'//
    //undefined reference to `base base::createInstanceGeneric(int param1, int param2)'//
    base test3 = childOne::createInstanceOfBaseViaGeneric(0,1); //Question 1 and 2
    test3.update(2);
    calledLaterForSomeStuff(test3);

    //undefined reference to `childOne base::createInstanceGeneric<childOne>(int param1, int param2)'
    //undefined reference to `childOne base::createInstanceGeneric(int param1, int param2)'
    childOne test4 = childOne::createInstanceOfSelfViaGeneric(0,1); //Question 3
    test4.update(3);
    calledLaterForSomeStuff(test4); 
}
//END app.cpp
```

Comment: Any time you post questions that involves build errors, please include the full and complete copy-pasted (as text) build output in the question itself. If line numbers are referenced in the error message, then add comments on those lines.

Comment: There are no "generics" in C++, and that [compiles](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9438c7409769f36d) after fixing all the typos.

Comment: Ok , i specified that the contents lays in his own files. Fixed typos.  The example is just a simple version what im doing, or try to do, in my projekt. And there i get reference erros all the time. So the qestion still is. can/should i deklare more template for all expected types and can i  doing it the child class eather?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it works all out of the box.
I had the implemententation of the template inside the cpp file. But its only allowed in the hpp.

Now its works.

Case CLOSED